# Is there anything that implements a fast random access list in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, hashtable

I have found `OrderedDictionary` but it doesn't do quite what I'd like. `OrderedDictionary` seems to present either a dictionary or a list view of the data, but you can't cross over between them so well.

E.g.

```
OrderedDictionary mylist = new OrderedDictionary();

mylist.Add(1, "Hello");
mylist.Add(4, "World");
mylist.Add(7, "Foo");
mylist.Add(9, "Bar");
```

With this code, I can directly access `mylist[7]` and get `"Foo"`, or I can iterate over the contents in the correct order, but I can't quickly answer the question "What follows Foo in the list?"

What I'd like is something like:

```
mylist.GetNode(7).Next.Value => "Bar"
```

Is there anything available in .NET and C# that can perform this task?

Comment: N.B doesn't `mylist[7]` try to return the 7th item in the `OrderedDictionary`, rather than the entry with key `7`? (`OrderedDictinoary` has both `object` and `int` indexers :-/)

Comment: I had a similar question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157140/net-4-0-indexer-with-observablecollection

Comment: @Rawling - good point. The int here is an index. We can assume for arguments sake that I wrapped the key up in a nice comparable object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) class (yes, we must beat that guy, which called `SortedList` this name).

```
static class SortedListExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetNextValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> list, TKey key)
    {
        var indexOfKey = list.IndexOfKey(key);

        if (indexOfKey == -1)
            return default(TValue);

        if (++indexOfKey == list.Count)
            return default(TValue);

        return list.Values[indexOfKey];
    }
}

var myList = new SortedList<int, string>
{
    { 1, "Hello" },
    { 4, "World" },
    { 7, "Foo" },
    { 9, "Bar" },
};

Console.WriteLine(myList.GetNextValueOrDefault(7)); // "Bar"
Console.WriteLine(myList.GetNextValueOrDefault(9)); // null
```

Comment: Specifically using `IndexOfKey` and then `Values[i + 1]`? Also, [the generic version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) would be preferable if it's appropriate.

Comment: @Rawling: thanks, I've missed a link. Updated with the code sample.

Comment: Looks like there's also a GetByIndex method for .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just add one to your index?

```
mylist[3] == "Foo";
mylist[3 + 1] == "Bar";
```

If the data structure supports random access I can't see why you'd want linked-list style behavior tacked on.

**Edit**

It appears though that `OrderedDictionary` can take an index as well as a key [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132598.aspx)

Otherwise you can pretty easily just add your own 'Next' pointer:

```
class DictionaryNode {
  public int? Next { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}


// Inside the appropriate class
int? lastKey = null;

void AddItem(int key, string value) {
  mylist.Add(key, new DictionaryNode { Next = null, Value = value });
  if (lastKey.HasValue) {
    mylist[lastKey].Next = key;
  }
  lastKey = key;
}
```

Comment: Assume that the ordering is random, but ascending. I'll update the Q

Comment: How can order be random and ascending?

Comment: I think he meant the key is random but the order is ascending.

Comment: yeah, what @RonWarholic said.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but you can do it on the fly like this:

```
OrderedDictionary mylist = new OrderedDictionary(); 
mylist.Add(1, "Hello"); 
mylist.Add(4, "World"); 
mylist.Add(7, "Foo"); 
mylist.Add(9, "Bar");

int key = 7;
Console.WriteLine("value: " + mylist[key as object]);
var nextKeys = mylist.Keys.Cast<int>().Where(i => i > key);
if (nextKeys.Count() == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("next value: (none)");
else
    Console.WriteLine("next value: " + mylist[nextKeys.Min() as object]);
```